# Execute Task if var in nested List is true in Ansible

Tags: ansible, nested-lists

I'm trying to execute a Task in Ansible if a Variable in a nested Stack is true, but don't manage to get it work...

My List looks something like this:

```
apache_vhosts_ssl:
  - servername: local.host.com
    documentroot: "/var/www/html/web"
  - servername: webcontent1.com
    documentroot: "/var/www/webcontent1.com/web"
  - servername: webcontent2.com
    use_certbot: true
    documentroot: "/var/www/webcontent2.com/web"
  - servername: webcontent3.com
    documentroot: "/var/www/webcontent3.com/web"
    use_certbot: true
```

I tried to Debug the nested list but failed, so i want to achieve two things:

1. If in List is at least one `use_certbot: true`, than do a Task
2. Get a list of `servername` who has the `use_certbot: true` to use in that task

For any Ideas,hinds, or even answers would be perfect, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "Execute this task for {{ srv_list }}"
      when: srv_list|length > 0
      vars:
        srv_list: "{{ apache_vhosts_ssl|
                      selectattr('use_certbot', 'defined')|
                      selectattr('use_certbot')|
                      map(attribute='servername')|
                      list }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: Execute this task for ['webcontent2.com', 'webcontent3.com']
```

Comment: this looks very promising, and I will implement it and test it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using list variables I suggest you to add "use_certbot: false" and not to leave this item empty for the servers, that do not have use_certbot.
your vars file should look like this.

```
apache_vhosts_ssl:
  - servername: local.host.com
    documentroot: "/var/www/html/web"
    use_certbot: false
  - servername: webcontent1.com
    documentroot: "/var/www/webcontent1.com/web"
    use_certbot: false
  - servername: webcontent2.com
    use_certbot: true
    documentroot: "/var/www/webcontent2.com/web"
  - servername: webcontent3.com
    documentroot: "/var/www/webcontent3.com/web"
    use_certbot: true
```

playbook like this:

```
- name: playbook name
  hosts: localhost
  vars_files:
    - varsfilename.yml
  tasks:
    - name: task name
      debug:
        msg: "{{ item.servername }}"
      loop: "{{ apache_vhosts_ssl }}"
      when: "{{ item.use_certbot}}"
```

good luck